# How do I map key value pairs from a dictionary to an array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, parsing

I have code that allows me to parse a nested JSON file.  The result of decoding gives me a dictionary, as shown below, which consists of a string and an object that contains 5 items.  I am attempting to map the dictionary to an array of type [(Date,Double)] with the code below but it fails.  Xcode underlines the = sign and states "type of expression is ambiguous without more context".  I do not know why.  Any assistance helping me to understand my error will be appreciated.

```
    var timeSeriesData: [(Date, Double)] = []

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url) // Works
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(VOOSeries.self, from: data) // Works
    print(decoded.timeSeries) // produces the following:

    [
     "2014-09-17": 
      Stocks.VOOValues(open: "184.1100", high: "184.9200", low: "183.2000",
      close: "184.0800", volume: "975000"), 

     "2016-10-25": 
      Stocks.VOOValues(open: "197.1300", high: "197.3900", low: "196.4800",
      close: "196.7100", volume: "1464904")
    ] 

     self.timeSeriesData = decoded.timeSeries.map {
     ( dateFormatter.date(from: $0.key)!, Double($0.value.close) )
     }.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 } // Xcode does not like the assignment i.e. =
```

Comment: One suggestion for when you are decoding your data. You can decode straight into a date rather than a string using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy. This should fix the ambiguity.

Comment: the problem is in `Double($0.value.close)`, it returns an optional.
Try something like this: `Double($0.value.close) ?? 0.0`

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be to make the date a property in VOOValues and convert and assign it during decoding, then you wouldn’t need to use an array of tuples

Comment: Thanks.  Adding ?? 0.0 worked.  I have done the conversion during decoding but am just playing with difference approaches.  Apples .DateDecodingStrategy does look interesting.  Will try that next.